# Change image src

Tags: javascript, dom

Hy
just can't make it work

```
function changeImage()
{
    element=document.getElementById("myimage")
    if (element.src.match("bulb_on"))
    {
        element.src="bulb_off.jpg";
    }
    else
    {
        element.src="bulb_on.jpg";
    }
}
```

This works fine but I try to, when the bulbs change, the black.jpg dissapears too. On bulboff there is a black img over the screen, on bulb on I want that the black image dissapears or instead put a transparent over it.

You know what I mean, on bulboff there is a black screen, on bulbon the black img (black screen) dissapears, when it dissapears the bulbon will still be visible and the blog content. Again on bulbon click the bulbof shows instead and the black screen, just the bulboff is visible.

```
    <img src="black.jpg" width="100%" height="100%">
    <div id="div"></div>
    <div id="bulb"><img src="bulb_off.jpg" id="myimage" onClick="changeImage()" width="100px" height="180px">
```

Is that possible without too much code?
Thanks

Comment: First of all, Line 3 is missing a semicolon at the end

Comment: Make a JSFiddle, displaying your problem

Comment: @MarkKramer: That missing `;` won't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a black image. A single `div` is enough:

```
<div id="black"></div>
```

For this, make a CSS:

```
div#black {
    background-color: black;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Now, just set its `display` to `block` when you want it visible or to `none` when you want to hide it.

Any more complex, you'd probably want to create CSS classes for "lights on" and "lights off" states of the "black" `div` and just change the classes, instead of `display` and any other properties you might want to change.